# jq json array mixed (duplicated) results

Tags: json, iteration, jq

I have a JSON array, which I want to extract values from (using jq):

This is a reduced example

```
{
  "query": "",
  "results": [
  {
      "id": 111,
      ...
      "buyer": {
        "email": "mail1@mail.com",
        ...
        "billing_info": {
          "doc_number": "123"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 222,
      ...
      "buyer": {
        "email": "mail2@mail.com",
        ...
        "billing_info": {
          "doc_number": "456"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, I'm using this filter:

```
{user: .results[].id, mail: .results[].buyer.email, buyer: .results[].buyer.billing_info.doc_number}
```

And I'm getting a "full join" result.

```
{"user":111,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":111,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
{"user":111,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":111,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
```

What I want is to filter some fields from the full object. So in this example, I have 2 objects, so I want 2 results:

```
{"user":111,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
```

Here is a snippet from my example:

https://jqplay.org/s/nM1WzWRmnK

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to "lift" the iterator (`.results[]`) to the front:

```
.results[] 
| {user: .id, mail: .buyer.email, buyer: .buyer.billing_info.doc_number}
```

With the -c command-line option, this produces:

```
{"user":111,"mail":"mail1@mail.com","buyer":"123"}
{"user":222,"mail":"mail2@mail.com","buyer":"456"}
```

It might help to think of `(ARRAY[] | ...)` in jq as being like `for (x in ARRAY) {...}` in other languages.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I've been playing with the array itself ( like []?, [*], [?]) for 2 hours straight.